# Can a missed patent opportunity be made up

Tags: patentability, law

My grandfather created a mobile self-storage business in San Diego in the early 80s.  Although the concept is very big now (like Door-to-Door), at the time he had not heard of anyone else doing something similar.

He was told there was no way to patent the idea, so he never tried.  I would have thought he could file a `utility patent` on the process of moving a fully loaded storage room (trucks, cranes, trailers, weight distribution, loading ramps, and every other piece he worked out) and effectively had rights to the idea.

*Assuming* I'm right, is there any recourse 30 years later on the missed patent opportunity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thirty years later - absolutely none. Given the lifetime of a patent is ~20 years, it would have expired by now, in any case.

Comment: In the more general case where less time had passed, is there recourse?  Let's say 5 years after inventing something, you discover you *could have* patented it.

Comment: In the US, you may get a 1-year period after which it will be considered prior art. Other countries, not even that. Filing a provisional application does give 1-year for filing the non-provisional (full) patent application, holding your place as it were.